# How to change the orientation to landscape for specific views?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a View in my application. That particular view i want to show in Landscape orientation. 
When The user comes to that view i want to force the user to change the device orientation. when user goes to an other view it has to reset ti. How can i do it?

Comment: Is it only for a single View ? And how many times does that view comes ?

Comment: @VenkatManohar Only once. Means when ever user clicks a button that viewController will be loaded so when it is loaded i want to change the orientation.

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:NO]; which orientation you want just place it there ... it works

Comment: Yes I got it. I have posted my code.                                         Thank you... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Got the answer

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];

```
float   angle = M_PI/2;  //rotate 180°, or 1 π radians
self.view.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angle, 0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

Comment: @AndreyChevozerov : then how to get it?

Answer (score 3):

In it's view controller implement two messages:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

And that's all.